# Modeling a point following another point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose you have a point starting at the origin $(0,0),$ i.e., $$(x(0)=0,y(0)=0).$$ 
We'll denote its coordinates with  $(x(t),y(t)),$ and it is tracking another point with constant velocity $v$. This point lies a few units to the right, i.e., $(x_0,0).$ The second point is going directly upwards with parametric coordinates $$(x_0,vt).$$

In figure 1, this is what the curve will look like for an instantaneous amount of time.

[image]

*figure 1*

Using this, we can derive that

\begin{align*} \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}&=v\,dt \\ 
\dfrac{v\,dt}{x_0}&=\dfrac{dy}{dx},
\end{align*}

which implies

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2}&=v \\ 
\frac{v\,dt}{x_0}&=\frac{dy}{dx}.
\end{align*}

However I got stuck here and I wasn't able to set up a nice differential equation. I took a different approach and tried to generalize recursively what the curve would look like as you can see in figure 2
[image]

*figure 2*

Let $$x_n=x(n\,dt), y_n=y(n\,dt)$$ and using properties of similar triangles and shared angles, we'll find

$$x_n=v\,dt \cdot \cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{nv\,dt−y_{n−1}}{x_0−x_{n−1}}\right)\right)+x_{n−1} \\ y_n=v\,dt \cdot \sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{nv\,dt−y_{n−1}}{x_0−x_{n−1}}\right)\right)+y_{n−1}$$

which implies

$$x_n=\frac{v\,dt}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{nv\,dt-y_{n-1}}{x_0-x_{n-1}}\right)^{\!2}}}+x_{n-1} \\ y_n=\frac{(v\,dt)\frac{nv\,dt−y_{n−1}}{x_0−x_{n−1}}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{nv\,dt-y_{n-1}}{x_0-x_{n-1}}\right)^{\!2}}}+y_{n-1}$$

However my progress stops here. Maybe I can set up a differential equation by reversing Euler's method through the recursive method? I am unsure of the most simple way to do this. Any ideas on finding $(x(t),y(t))?$

Comment: You might find the tractrix article helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix

Comment: I am sure you can set up some differential equation. Reversing euler's method will be too difficult.